# Razor Form not posting all the rows of DataTables to the MVC Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, datatables

I have a `DataTable` with 100 editable records in a `View`. I can edit records and post them back to `MVC Action`. If I destroy `DataTable` and post my Form I get all 100 records in form collections. On the other hand, if I don't destroy the `DataTable` and click on submit, then I get only first 10 records.

Here is my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Events", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <button type="submit">  Save </button>

        <table id="tblEvents">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   // Header
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 // Records
            </tbody>
        </table>

}
```

Scripts:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var table = $('#tblEvents').DataTable();

        $("form").on('submit', function () {
            // If I remove this I get only first 10 Records.
            table.destroy();
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963732/datatables-and-jquery-post?rq=1 might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

try using ajax call for submitting form, rather than reloading whole page, it might work